# Security warning with Jssor

Tags: jquery, jssor

I'm getting a Security Warning with IE8 on the Jssor slider. Here's the current configuration:

- Site is running HTTPS only.
- All references to the jQuery libraries are relative to a scripts folder.
- All URLs to images are relative to an images folder.
- I cannot test this on other browsers; my corporation will not
  allow an upgrade or any other browser.
- There are no AJAX calls on the page. The slider is using hard coded HTML.

The security warning doesn't come up at first -- the slider will load and display the image comment. The first slide will animate out, but as soon as the second slide trys to transition, the security warning pops up.

The security message states (since I can't upload a screenshot):

"**Do you want to view only the webpage content that was delivered securly?**"
"This webpage contains content that will not be delivered using a secure HTTPS connection, which could compromise the security of the entire webpage."
Options: "More Info", "Yes", "No"

I have checked the page source for static URLs to an HTTP address, but I can't find anything that would trigger this.

Everything on the page loads regardless if I click 'Yes' or 'No'.

Any ideas on this one? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I researched internet and read some articles, it caused by non https resource reference in a web page.

Check all resource references like js, css, image urls in your page.
Replace src="http://..." with src="https://..."

Btw, please leave me the url of your demo to have a test.

Comment: comments belong to the comments section. this is an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reference: Internet Explorer 8 Mixed Content Handling

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264315%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

After experimenting with the code, I found the problem.

A DIV tag had an background-image (for the loading.gif logo) set with a relative URL. I changed it to an absolute URL and the security warning went away!

Why would it do this? All the other relative URLs do not have a problem.

Comment: I have no idea yet. I'd say it's a topic about ie 8 and it's not business of jssor slider.